# Android how to remove blur from image on touch using gpuimage

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpuimage

I need to remove blur from the image wherever user touch on screen from an image and save it's state. I have been using the following library.

https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage

I have used the following example which is using android-gpuimage

https://github.com/ufo22940268/Android-Blur

It removes blur from image wherever I touch but when I touch other parts of the image the later touch point become blur again.

```java
public void onTouch(MotionEvent event){
   float y = event.getY(mActionIndex);
   float x = event.getX(mActionIndex);
   focus(x, y);
   requestRender();
}

private void focus(float x, float y) {
    GPUImageFilter filter = getFilter();
    if (filter != null && filter instanceof GPUImageBoxBlurFilter) {
      GPUImageBoxBlurFilter blurFilter = (GPUImageBoxBlurFilter) filter;
            blurFilter.focus(x, y);
    }
}

public void focus(final float x, final float y) {
  runOnDraw(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        float[] focusLocation = new float[]{normalize(x, mOutputWidth), -normalize(y, mOutputHeight)};
        GPUImageFilter filter = mFilters.get(0);
        int screenRatioLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(filter.getProgram(), "focusLocation");
                filter.setFloatVec2(screenRatioLocation, focusLocation);

        filter = mFilters.get(1);
        screenRatioLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(filter.getProgram(), "focusLocation");
                filter.setFloatVec2(screenRatioLocation, focusLocation);
                initTexelOffsets();
            }
        });
    }

    private float normalize(float x, int outputWidth) {
        return x / outputWidth * 2 - 1;
    }
protected void initTexelOffsets() {
        float ratio = getHorizontalTexelOffsetRatio();
        GPUImageFilter filter = mFilters.get(0);
        int texelWidthOffsetLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(filter.getProgram(), "texelWidthOffset");
        int texelHeightOffsetLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(filter.getProgram(), "texelHeightOffset");
        filter.setFloat(texelWidthOffsetLocation, ratio / mOutputWidth);
        filter.setFloat(texelHeightOffsetLocation, 0);

        ratio = getVerticalTexelOffsetRatio();
        filter = mFilters.get(1);
        texelWidthOffsetLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(filter.getProgram(), "texelWidthOffset");
        texelHeightOffsetLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(filter.getProgram(), "texelHeightOffset");
        filter.setFloat(texelWidthOffsetLocation, 0);
        filter.setFloat(texelHeightOffsetLocation, ratio / mOutputHeight);
    }
```

Whenever user select unblur then touching on image should remove blur from that point and save image so that when user touch another point both or more points should be unblured.
Need vice versa of this as well, if user select blur it should blur that point.

As I am pretty noob in opengl any help will be greately appreciated.

Comment: any progress for this?

Comment: No, Didn't get time to explore further.